# Exact effect of ZipArchive::Create too ambiguous

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

The exact effect of ZipArchive::CREATE is too ambiguous per the guides I have found online. I have this 'if' statement inside a 'foreach' loop. What I want it to do is create the zip file if it is not already there, add the file, and then close it. Otherwise, if it already exists, I just want it to open the zip file and add the file and then close it. My concern is that this code will see that the zip file already exists and will jump to the 'else' part of the statement.

```
if($zip[$i]->open($filePath + $filename, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
{
    $zip[$i]->addFile($file);
    $zip[$i]->close();
}
else
{
    //Do something else;
}
```

Comment: Check if is_file, if it is, just ZipArchive:addFile it, if it's not then ZipArchive:open and add afterwards.

Comment: But will ZipArchive::CREATE give me an undesirable outcome if the zip file already exists?

Comment: Your code will work as expected, you can test it. `ZipArchive::CREATE` is a flag which will say the `open()` method to create the zip file if it is missing. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php#ziparchive.constants.create

Comment: Progman, thank you for the answer. I had to ask as I was not able to test it here on these computers at work. We have very strange constraints and restrictions when it comes to code.